# No uncaught reference error while accessing let variable outside code block?

Tags: javascript, scoping

While learning javascript, I came across 2 different code snippets and I am confused about the scoping of variables declared using let/const. I know that variables declared using let/ const are block-scoped, meaning you can't access them outside the block in which they are declared.

The following two snippets contradict each other, why is that so?

**Snippet 1**: ReferenceError as expected

```
const  calculateArea = function(radius){
  let area = 3.14 * radius ** 2;
  console.log(area);
}
console.log(area)
```

**Output of snippet 1:**

```
ReferenceError: area is not defined
    at <anonymous>:12:13
    at mn (<anonymous>:16:5455)
```

**Snippet 2**: Why no error???

```
 let age = 30;
 if(true){
    let age = 40;
  let name = 'Peter';
  console.log('Inside if block: ', name, age);
 }
  console.log('Outside if block: ', name, age);
```

**Output of snippet 2:**

```
Inside if block: 
Peter
40
Outside if block: 
30
```

Why is there space before age while logging outside if block statement to console?
Why was there no reference error this time?

Comment: @santra72 The problem is, it doesn't throw an error since `name` is a property of the global (i. e. the `window`) object and so constitutes a valid reference. Please get your facts right before commenting (if you want to verify this, open your browser's console and type `name`). Masking that with the definition of a local variable merely makes that one temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about scoping. `name` is a global property in browsers, i.e. `window.name`. You will get a `ReferenceError` in Node.js.

Reference: [Window: name property - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)